# Where is Max Stack Size set on ORACLE database machines running ORACLE LINUX 7 (on top of VMWARE)

Tags: oracle, stack-size

We had an issue where we were advised by oracle our stacksize was too small - Doing ulimit -Ss as the oracle user this showed 10240k (a previously recommended setting) - However when looking at an oracle process - pmon for example and then doing cd /proc/;cat limits - we would see the Max  stack size of 2mb.... so it seems the 10mb setting was not having an effect

Oracle recommended adding the line "oracle soft stack 16384" to /etc/security/limits.conf but this line seems to have no effect on my servers (also of course re-booted after adding the line).

I'd be grateful if someone could shed some light on where it is actually being set

Comment: This site is usually more for programming/developer questions. You can try posting at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you use systemd? If you start database via script executed from SystemD then security/limits.config intentionally ignored. And you have to set limits one again in systemd unit file.